# How can I perform a multi-table join and update operation in GridDB using SQL?

Tags: sql, join, data-manipulation, griddb, multi-table

I have multiple containers in my GridDB database and I need to perform a join operation involving multiple tables, followed by an update operation based on the joined results. However, I'm not sure how to achieve this using GridDB's SQL syntax.

Here's an example of what I want to achieve:

```
UPDATE container1
SET container1.column1 = 'updated_value'
FROM container1
JOIN container2 ON container1.commonAttribute = container2.commonAttribute
WHERE container2.column2 = 'condition_value'
```

In this example, I want to join container1 and container2 based on a common attribute and update column1 in container1 to **updated_value** for rows that satisfy a certain condition on column2 in container2. How can I write the equivalent multi-table join and update operation in GridDB's SQL syntax? Are there any specific functions or syntax I should use to perform these GridDB operations?